# Is there a performance benefit of enabling Path MTU Discovery in IPv6?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, ipv6, mtu

1) Is there a performance benefit of enabling Path MTU Discovery in IPv6 (TCP) sockets?

2) If so does the benefit only apply to persistent connections? How long does the kernel remember MTU for a specific destination host?

3) When it is enabled does it start with a larger packet and come down in case of failure and an MTU discovery, or start with a packet size of 1280 and goes up until it hits a speed bump? Does the behavior differ between `IP_PMTUDISC_WANT` and `IP_PMTUDISC_DO` settings?

NB: In case there are differences in implementation I am interested with regards to Linux.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the Linux implementation. There is a benefit, period. Outgoing IP packets and TCP segments are pre-fragmented to the correct size.

Comment: @EJP Thanks. I mentioned Linux just in case there is a difference in implementation among OSs, which has significance for the 3rd part of my question.